# How Elixir can read remote node mnesia table

Tags: elixir, mnesia

I am trying use Elixir to write program to access mnesia. I run iex shell in amazon linux. I tried to connect another node using

```
Node.connect(:'hello@abc.com')
```

which return true, then I want to run mnesia command on this remote node, I issue

```
  :mneisa.info
```

However, it only returns local node mnesia info. How can I access the connected remote node's mnesia database?

I have tried rpc_call, it works. But is it having more direct method to get the data from remote node mnesia.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try:

```
Node.spawn :'hello@abc.com', fn -> :mneisa.info end
```

Comment: See http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/ and click on Node in the side bar for more useful documentation - glad to assist.