# Erlang reading remote mnesia node

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I am trying to read the remote Mnesia node using an Erlang command. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am running Erlang 17 OTP. I tried to start my local Mnesia node by issuing

```
mnesia:start().
```

And then I tried to connect to remote node with

```
mnesia.start([{extra_db_nodes, [:'abc@def.com']}]).
```

It returns true. Then I issue the `mnesia:info()`, however, it only returns the local Mnesia info. My question is how can I issue the Mnesia command to a remote node from my local node? I am wondering how I can get the Mnesia data of `extra_db_nodes` in my local node?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642263/how-elixir-can-read-remote-node-mnesia-table?

Comment: Sorry for the not clarity of my question , it is not duplicate of the question. For that question, I am asking the elixir way to access remote mnesia node. This question, I hope I can get how to use erlang command to access the remote mnesia node.

Comment: Hi, am I asking an impossible solution? I think I can put in in simple, it is how to read remote node mnesia info from my node. Thanks

Comment: You seem to be asking at least two different questions and neither one looks like your real underlying question. Do you want to know how to execute code on a remote node? Or are you asking how to distribute the database? Please try to rephrase your question as an actual problem you're trying to solve (like "I want to access the same piece of data on two machines").

Comment: `syntax error before: ':'`